# Is there any way to exit from function only after some object is loaded?

Tags: c#

I've created some UserControl. Here is its constructor:

```
public ZoomableChart()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.mainChart = new MainChart();
            this.mainChart.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(delegate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
                {
                    this.zoomChart = new ZoomChart();
                });
        }
```

I don't want to exit from it until mainChart.Loaded event handler execute. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `AutoResetEvent` and wait for it.

```
public ZoomableChart()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AutoResetEvent waitLoaded = new AutoResetEvent (false);
        this.mainChart = new MainChart();
        this.mainChart.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(delegate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.zoomChart = new ZoomChart();
            waitLoaded.Set ();
        });
        waitLoaded.WaitOne ();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

```
public ZoomableChart()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AutoResetEvent loaded = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            this.mainChart = new MainChart();
            this.mainChart.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(delegate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
                {
                    this.zoomChart = new ZoomChart();
                    loaded.Set();
                });
            //better to use timeout here
            loaded.WaitOne();
        }
```

**Edit**: Thanks to Tim. This code will deadlock if this thread was supposed to execute the load. Make sure that this don't happen in same thread.

Comment: How do you know which thread raises the `Loaded` event? If the current thread is the one that's supposed to load the chart, then this code will deadlock.

Comment: "Make sure that this don't happen in same thread" - this looks like WPF code, so I'm guessing this will be on the same thread. I don't know enough WPF to suggest a fix, though.

Comment: @Tim Robinson not necessary, you can create control on another thread and events will happen in main message-pumping thread. or i am wrong.

Comment: OK, but all the control creation code is inside this method, which is the `ZoomableChart` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
AutoResetEvent are = new AutoResetEvent(false);

public XoomableChar()
{
InitializeComponent();

this.mainChar = new MainChart();
this.mainChart.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(delegate sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
this.zoomChart = new ZoomChart();
are.Set();
}
are.WaitOne();
}
```